# How to install python packages wihout accessing external repositories?

Tags: python, pip, dependencies

Currently I install my packages via this command

```
pip install -U --no-index --find-links=wheels -r requirements.txt
```

Each dependency is looked up in the "wheels" folder and installed from the appropriate wheel if it was found. Otherwise pip downloads the dependency from the Internet and installs it. If there is no Internet connection, it tries to look it up in the local repos.

How do I make pip install dependencies from the "wheels" folder and local repos only? Even if I restrict access to the Internet (using a firewall, for example), it still tries to reach out to the external repos for several times and only then does it download packages from the local ones.

This is what my requirements.txt file looks like:

```
--index-url https://pypi.org/simple/
--extra-index-url https://my.local.repo.com/...
foo==1.2.3
bar==4.5.6
...
```

Answer (score 0):

from a pc that connected to internet :

```
pip download yourpackage
```

copy "yourpackage.tar.gz" to server in server :

```
pip install "path/yourpackage.tar.gz"
```

if package have ".whl" file :

```
pip install "path/yourpackage-version.whl"
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is correct, there is just a syntax problem with find-links param, according to docs is --find-links location:

```
pip install -U --no-index --find-links /dir/to/wheels -r requirements.txt
```